# How to handle windows event using a c++ class?

Tags: c++, event-handling

I want to write a C++ class that can be hooked with a windows event handle create by the `CreateEvent` function, so that when the event is signaled, it can be handled by the class I write. Is there a way to do so?

Specifically, I want to create a class that can handle the skeleton data generated by Kinect. The data are dealt by firstly creating a handle to an event object using `CreateEvent` function, and then call the

```
m_pNuiSensor->NuiSkeletonTrackingEnable( 
            /* [in] */ HANDLE hNextFrameEvent,
            /* [in] */ DWORD dwFlags)
```

function so that when the frame data is available, the `hNextFrameEvent` will be signaled. I was wondering if I can handle the event when it is signaled in the class I created.

Thanks!

Comment: events created with `CreateEvent` are not handled.. they are used for synchronization. I think you are confusing windows events with the synchronization primitives.

Comment: please give some more details about what you are trying to do!

Comment: I've added more info to my question.@Miky Dinescu

Comment: Wait on the event. When the wait completes, the event has occurred. Then call your class.